# Why is gpu device used not consistent with log info?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, tensorflow2.0

My machine have 4 GPUs, and when I run the code, at the beginning I already set:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```

Through nvidia-smi command I can see that gpu 1 is actually used. However, the tensorflow log on the terminal shows that gpu 0 is used:

```
2021-09-24 02:27:55.691073: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:0d.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-09-24 02:27:55.691123: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-09-24 02:27:55.694585: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-09-24 02:27:55.698234: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-09-24 02:27:55.698776: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-09-24 02:27:55.702390: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-09-24 02:27:55.703656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-09-24 02:27:55.709853: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2021-09-24 02:27:55.710078: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-09-24 02:27:55.711069: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-09-24 02:27:55.711917: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0

...

2021-09-24 02:27:55.906440: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-09-24 02:27:55.906571: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2021-09-24 02:27:57.342555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-09-24 02:27:57.342608: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2021-09-24 02:27:57.342619: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2021-09-24 02:27:57.342980: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-09-24 02:27:57.343982: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-09-24 02:27:57.344891: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14419 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:0d.0, compute capability: 7.0)
```

I have two questions:

1. GPU 0 is indeed used, but by another process. In my code, it is using gpu 1. I am wondering why the log above is consistent with the device actually used?
2. Also, Tensorflow 2 should be automatically detecting available GPUs and use it. If I don't add this line:

   os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

The log shows that it is trying to use gpu= 0 and produces an out of memory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable *remaps* whichever devices you select so that with respect to your CUDA process, those devices (in your list) appear to CUDA as if they started at zero.  So when you do:

   ```
   os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
   ```

   Thereafter, CUDA sees that device as if it were device 0.
2. Just because a GPU is in use by another process/user, does not mean that it is "not available" for you to use.   CUDA doesn't prevent two users or two processes from trying to use the same GPU, and in some cases that scenario is sensible/effective.  So TF sees it as a usable device, attempts to use it, and runs out of memory.  That is one typical reason why people use the environment variable listed in 1 above.  The environment variable will make only certain devices "visible" or "usable" to your TF process.

Comment: Also, I am seeing that another process shows that its gpu usage reading at 10%, the last column of the nvidia-smi command, but its memory is almost fully used. And if my process use this gpu, it shows an outofmemory error. Is this normal? What's the relationship between memory usage and the gpu usage on the nvidia-smi command?

Comment: There is no relationship whatsoever between memory usage and GPU usage.  You can have approximately 100% GPU utilization with little or almost no memory utilization.  You can have full memory utilization with no (0%) GPU utilization reported by `nvidia-smi`.  What you see here is a function of what your application is doing.  Allocating device memory? -> memory utilization.  Running GPU kernels?  -> GPU utilization.

Comment: Yes, its normal that if a GPU has all of its memory utilized (however that came about), and then your process tries to use that GPU and allocate device memory on it, that an out of memory error will be reported.

Comment: Is this memory on nvidia-smi the same as cpu memory? My other memory is much larger. If not same, while a program is using GPU, will it only use GPU's memory and not other much larger memory?

Comment: No it is not the same as CPU memory. It is memory attached to your GPU.  I can't tell you how a non-specific program will behave.  A program might use CPU memory (which really has nothing to do with `nvidia-smi` reporting) or it might use GPU memory, or both.  Probably both, for GPU-enabled programs, to some degree.

Comment: I understand better now and thanks.